# How to return a rolling window in pandas which starts from middle?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to compute a function on rolling windows from the dataframe. This function takes a long time to compute, and I don't need its values to be computed from the start of the dataframe. How could I start pandas rolling window from middle.
for data_window in df.rolling(window=100):
do computation on data_window

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example? Why don't you just slice the part you need to use (`df.iloc[start:stop].rolling(window=100)`)?

Comment: I think, this will work: `.rolling(window=100, center=True)`

Comment: @mozway, Thank you for your comment. I want the dataframe to be used before start for computing. May be its better to say (df.iloc[start-100:stop].rolling(window=100)).